# Instead of Insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I want create a instead of insert trigger where It should not allow any record with same VersionNo or having VersionNo as NULL

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My requirement is quite simple. 1) I Want to create a instead of insert trigger with constraint 1) VersionNo should not be same 2) VersionNo should not be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a trigger for this.  The right way to do this is using constraints:

```
alter table t alter column version int not null;
```

Then mandate that it be unique:

```
alter table add constraint unq_t_version unique (version);
```

If you want a combination of columns to be unique, such as `(SGID, Version)`, then use that for the unique constraint instead of a single column.

Comment: Ya sir, we can do this using constraints. But the requirement is I have to implement the same using a Trigger.

Comment: @BaarathiVenkatesh . . . That is sad.  You should only use triggers when absolutely necessary, and there are better examples for handling them.  You should be learning the right way to express logic in SQL.

Comment: Okay sir,Thank You